# define outer polygon from pixel pattern

Tags: algorithm, polygon, pixel

I have a contiguous pattern of pixel given in x and y coordinates, e.g.

```
0000000000
00xxxx0000
xxxxxxxx00
xxxxxx0000
00xxxxxxxx
0xxxxxxxxx
```

where 'x' represents a marked pixel. Is there an efficient way/algorithm to determine the convex hull polygon, enclosing the pattern field?

Comment: No I dont mean convex hulls; i want to end up with a simple outline polygon of the marked pixels like so 0000000000
00xxxx0000
xxxxxxxx00
xxxxxx0000
00xxxxxxxx
0xxxxxxxxx

Comment: You said you want the convex hull; the outline you give is *not* convex.

Comment: Post your clarification as an edit to the original question, not as an answer or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, iterate through the grid.  For each 3x3 slice, if all entries are `x`, mark the cell to be cleared.  At the end of that pass, come back and clear all of the marked cells.